# cannot access this.props in load of highcharts

Tags: highcharts, react-native

```
render(){
        let conf={
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load:function(){
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(() =>{
                            var x = new Date().getTime() // current time
                            y = this.props.y
                            series.addPoint([x,y], true, true);
                        }, 900);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            }}}
```

I am not able to access **this.props.y** inside the load function and not even any constructor variable. 
I have tried using **arrow functions** instead of **function** and then the graph display nothing.
Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

*this* in your arrow function is bound to the chart object, not the component.

You can cache *this* in the variable in the render and then use it in the timeout.

```
render(){
    const component = this

    let conf={
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load:function(){
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(() =>{
                        var x = new Date().getTime() // current time
                        y = component.props.y
                        series.addPoint([x,y], true, true);
                    }, 900);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        }}}
```